# Facebook Graph API - Can't access some Pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

I am using an external server to retrieve events from multiple Facebook Pages. In about 1% of all cases, I get an error of the following type:

```
Unsupported get request. Object with ID '...' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api
```

The common link I've found between the Pages that aren't working is that they are kind of private: if you log out of Facebook, you can't access their page, even though you can access other pages.

I am using an App Access Token to do this. Is there a way to access these Pages' events anyway?

**UPDATE**

I've found some explanation in the Facebook Docs.

```
Permissions

For pages that are published, you need:

An app or user access token to view fields from fully public pages.
A user access token to view fields from restricted pages that this person is able to view (such as those restrict to certain demographics like location or age, or those only viewable by Page admins).
A page access token can also be used to view those restricted fields.
```

This probably means that these particular pages aren't "fully public pages". Is there still some work around?

Comment: _“Is there still some work around?”_ – read the last two sentences of what you just quoted yourself again.

Comment: Thanks for answering ! By page access token, don't they mean a token from the page itself? Which would by definition rule this out as a solution for me, no? Otherwise, I would love to know how to achieve this, because I'm currently unable to get any other token than a simple app access token.

Comment: Yes, to get a page access token, you need to be an admin of the page (or have the admin of a page log in to your app, and grant it permission.)

Comment: That makes sense. I guess there isn't much of a way around it then... And is there any way to use a user access token in a server-side script?

Comment: Sure, you just use it like you would any other access token, by passing it as an additional parameter named `access_token`